Making a metal detector in home, see if i am doing it propely and right
I'm making a metal detector at home, and I'm thinking about using a magnet because of the magnetic field that would help find metal. I was going to use hall sensors that would work and help, but I see that the version I'm going to buy has 1 output on one side and 3 on the other. I don't know which side I should put the magnet on, but moving forward, I would connect it to a battery and from the battery to a lamp so that when metal was detected the lamp would light up.. it would connect everything using copper wires. (it can get confusing but I'm just a 13-year-old child and I don't have any experience in this) I hope I can help, and this is the website for the sensor I'm going to buy.
Módulo Sensor de Efeito Hall 3144E

please if you can try dont using conplicated words, or just pronounce the entire meaning like ( pov : point of view )

please do not write a comment on your own question ... if you have anything to add, then edit the question instead

what would the metal detector be used for?

try something like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XYSj_dhv150

Building a well-tuned functional metal detector is not a beginner task. I’m not trying to scare you away, it’s a great learning experience in analog electronics, but don’t expect great results on your first attempt.

That's not how it works. The A3144E sensor is meant for detecting a magnet mounted on a spinning wheel for example, so you can calculate how fast the wheel spins. So it's for speed measurement.
That's why it has a digital output. It can only tell you whether there was the specified magnet in its proximity or not.

For a metal detector you need an analog output so you can evaluate the amount of change in the magnetic field that the metal does to it. As those changes are very small and you need a means to adjust it somehow.
If you want to build a metal detector yourself, you need some woodworking skills. As its main component is a huge detector coil that needs to be put on a wooden (or plastic) frame with a long handle attached, and you need to construct all that without screws or nails because, uh, they are made from metal and that would alarm the detector all the time.
This guy explains how to build a very simple metal detector, and he does so in Portugese.
